# How to add title in Jquery Slider for prev next buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, slider

How to add title in Jquery Slider for prev next buttons.
I tried on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/J9fqq/255/

screen - http://prntscr.com/co4o10

I have created jsfiddle so it will be more helpful for everyone to see everything whats going on
Maybe there is a similar slider?
Please, help

```
var slideWidth=300;
var sliderTimer;
$(function(){
$('.slidewrapper').width($('.slidewrapper').children().size()*slideWidth);
    sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide,10000);
    $('.viewport').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(sliderTimer);
    },function(){
        sliderTimer=setInterval(prevSlide,10000);
    });
    $('#next_slide').click(function(){
        clearInterval(sliderTimer);
        nextSlide();
        sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide,10000);
    });
    $('#prev_slide').click(function(){
        clearInterval(sliderTimer);
        prevSlide();
        sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide,10000);
    });
});

function nextSlide(){
    var currentSlide=parseInt($('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide>=$('.slidewrapper').children().size())
    {
        $('.slidewrapper').css('left',-(currentSlide-2)*slideWidth);  
        $('.slidewrapper').append($('.slidewrapper').children().first().clone()); 
        $('.slidewrapper').children().first().remove();
        currentSlide--;                        
    }
        $('.slidewrapper').animate({left: -currentSlide*slideWidth},300).data('current',currentSlide);


}

function prevSlide(){
    var currentSlide=parseInt($('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
    currentSlide--;
    if(currentSlide<0)
    {
        $('.slidewrapper').css('left',-(currentSlide+2)*slideWidth);  
        $('.slidewrapper').prepend($('.slidewrapper').children().last().clone()); 
        $('.slidewrapper').children().last().remove();
        currentSlide++;   
    }
    $('.slidewrapper').animate({left: -currentSlide*slideWidth},300).data('current',currentSlide);
}
```

Comment: do you mean how to show titles while hovering on `prev` and `next` buttons?

Comment: You can use title attribute in `<a>` tag for example `<a href='javascript: void(0)' title='Slider 3 ' id='prev_slide' class='arrows'>←</a>`

Comment: Amani, instead of arrows title

Comment: dinesh, but how to get title
<a href='javascript: void(0)' id='prev_slide' class='arrows'>Slider 3</a>

Comment: You update the html using jQuery.. Give min..

Comment: @Vova are you want slider name instead of arrow right?

Comment: @dinesh yes, like you wrote, needs the replace the ← → arrow, Like if slider 2 is active need link as ←(slider 1) and →(slider 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextSlide(){
    var currentSlide=parseInt($('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide>=$('.slidewrapper').children().size())
    {
        $('.slidewrapper').css('left',-(currentSlide-2)*slideWidth);  
        $('.slidewrapper').append($('.slidewrapper').children().first().clone()); 
        $('.slidewrapper').children().first().remove();
        currentSlide--;                        
    }
        $('.slidewrapper').animate({left: -currentSlide*slideWidth},300).data('current',currentSlide);
    console.log($('.slidewrapper').children().find('div.titleslider').html());
    $('#next_slide').html($('.slidewrapper').children().find('div.titleslider').html());

}
```

**console.log($('.slidewrapper').children().find('div.titleslider').html());
        $('#next_slide').html($('.slidewrapper').children().find('div.titleslider').html());**

You can try like this.

Comment: Yes, but how get title from prev and next slider

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please tell us properly.

Comment: he is asking for he needs the replace the ← → arrow, Like if slider 2 is active need link as ←(slider 1) and  →(slider 2). @Vova

Comment: I have just given an example. You can try like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **title** attribute:

```html
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="prev_slide" title="Prev" class="arrows">←</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="next_slide" title="Next" class="arrows">→</a>
```

Comment: .needs the replace the ← → arrow, Like if slider 2 is active need link as ←(slider 1) and →(slider 2)

Answer (score 0):

Just Add title="Previous" And Next For Anchors In Your Code .

```js
var slideWidth=300;
var sliderTimer;
$(function(){
$('.slidewrapper').width($('.slidewrapper').children().size()*slideWidth);
    sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide,10000);
    $('.viewport').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(sliderTimer);
    },function(){
        sliderTimer=setInterval(prevSlide,10000);
    });
    $('#next_slide').click(function(){
        clearInterval(sliderTimer);
        nextSlide();
        sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide,10000);
    });
    $('#prev_slide').click(function(){
        clearInterval(sliderTimer);
        prevSlide();
        sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide,10000);
    });
});

function nextSlide(){
    var currentSlide=parseInt($('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide>=$('.slidewrapper').children().size())
    {
        $('.slidewrapper').css('left',-(currentSlide-2)*slideWidth);  
        $('.slidewrapper').append($('.slidewrapper').children().first().clone()); 
        $('.slidewrapper').children().first().remove();
        currentSlide--;                        
    }
        $('.slidewrapper').animate({left: -currentSlide*slideWidth},300).data('current',currentSlide);
    
    
}

function prevSlide(){
    var currentSlide=parseInt($('.slidewrapper').data('current'));
    currentSlide--;
    if(currentSlide<0)
    {
        $('.slidewrapper').css('left',-(currentSlide+2)*slideWidth);  
        $('.slidewrapper').prepend($('.slidewrapper').children().last().clone()); 
        $('.slidewrapper').children().last().remove();
        currentSlide++;   
    }
    $('.slidewrapper').animate({left: -currentSlide*slideWidth},300).data('current',currentSlide);
}
```

```css
.viewport{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slidewrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}
.slide{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ff0000;
}
.second{
     background: #00ff00;   
}
.third{
     background: #0000ff;   
}
```

```html
<div class='viewport'>
    <ul class='slidewrapper' data-current=0>
        <li class='slide'>
            <div class="titleslider">
              Slider 1
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class='slide'>
            <div class="titleslider">
              Slider 2
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class='slide'>
            <div class="titleslider">
              Slider 3
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href='javascript: void(0)' id='prev_slide' class='arrows' title="Previous">←</a>
<a href='javascript: void(0)' id='next_slide' class='arrows' title="Next">→</a>
```

Comment: needs the replace the ← → arrow, Like if slider 2 is active need link as ←(slider 1) and →(slider 2)

Comment: Explain Clearly Your Requirement .